# mod_rewrite not redirecting for multilingual site when trailing slash missing

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am currently developing a multi-lingual website. Users can access the front page using URL with format below:

```
http://example.com/en/
http://example.com/fr/
```

Problem is here. URL without last "`/`" (`http://example.com/fr`) caused page not found problem

Here is the rule

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^./]+)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})(/(.*))?$ $3?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Another option would be to redirect if the trailing slash is missing:

```
RewriteRule ^/?[a-z]{2}$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```